# How can I group two same products to show them as one in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

[image: Database values]

*Now as u see in the database table. In this table, we have two oranges but have different prices because pack size. From this table, I want to get data in this way that on my project product view list oranges shows only once and if we go to the product detail we have a combo box where we can display the different size of pack from the table like oranges. **Oranges should we shown once from this table to the product list by grouping them and after going to oranges details we can see both the oranges packaging in a combo box.** *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, we can use the Django HTML tag **"regroup"** as shown in the code below, and u also have to change the query in the view.py and just order it by productID. For the given table in the image, I will post the code below.
**HTML**

```
  {% regroup transaction by productID as ProductList %}
  {% for productID in ProductList %}
  <div class="col-sm-3" id="productID" >
    <div class="product">
      <a href="{% url 'main:product-detail' productID.grouper.id %}" class="img-prod"><img class="img-fluid" src={{productID.grouper.product_image.url}} alt="" height="200px">
        <span class="status">%</span>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="text py-3 pb-4 px-3 text-center">
        <h3><a href="#">{{productID.grouper}}</a></h3>
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="pricing">
            <p class="price"><span class="mr-2 price-dc" id='id_price'>Rs. </span><span class="price-sale" id='id_sale_price'>Rs. </span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
          
          <select class="tranactionID" style="width: 250px;">
            <!-- <option value="none" selected disabled hidden>
              Select an Option
          </option> -->
            {% for val in productID.list %}
                <option price={{val.Price}} sale_price={{val.get_sale}} class="price_value" >{{val.AUID}} - {{val.Description}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
          </select>
         
         
        <!-- <div class="bottom-area d-flex px-3">
          <div class="m-auto d-flex"> -->
            <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' productID.grouper.id %}" class="d-inline" method="post">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow px-5 py-2" value="Add To Cart">
              {{cart_product_form}}
              {% csrf_token %}
              
              <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow px-5 py-2">Add to Cart</button> -->
            </form>
          <!-- </div> -->
        <!-- </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
 transaction = transactions.objects.filter(status='Enable').order_by('productID')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a model **Products** that will have a product name field and **ProductDetails** model that will reference Product model to get the name of the product, the ProductDetails mode will have description, price and other information about the product.

Lets hope this will help.
Happy coding